# Rewrite old image url with nginx

Tags: nginx

I have a single image that I renamed and need to redirect from the old image url to the new one my server uses `nginx`, I'm not having much success with the following rewrite:

```
rewrite ^/assets/avatar/avatar.png /assets/avatar/newavatar.png permanent;
```

Does someone know what is wrong?

Comment: You're trying to redirect with a rewrite?

Comment: Yes i haven`t formulated my question very well, what i want to do is a rewrite.

Comment: Please can you edit your question then. i.e. say if you want to redirect requests permanently or just rewrite?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use rewrite you need to use a full path to the new location

```
rewrite ^/assets/avatar/avatar.png http://example.com/assets/avatar/newavatar.png permanent;
```

A better way though is using a return

```
location /assets/avatar/avatar.png {
    return 301 $scheme://example.com/assets/avatar/newavatar.png;
}
```

If you want to just rewrite, you need to change `permanent` to `last` or `break`